# Scala downwards or decreasing for loop?

Tags: scala, iterator, loops, for-loop

In Scala, you often use an iterator to do a `for` loop in an increasing order like:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10){ code }
```

How would you do it so it goes from 10 to 1? I guess `10 to 1` gives an empty iterator (like usual range mathematics)?

I made a Scala script which solves it by calling reverse on the iterator, but it's not nice in my opinion, is the following the way to go?

```
def nBeers(n:Int) = n match {

    case 0 => ("No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer." +
               "\nGo to the store and buy some more, " +
               "99 bottles of beer on the wall.\n")

    case _ => (n + " bottles of beer on the wall, " + n +
               " bottles of beer.\n" +
               "Take one down and pass it around, " +
              (if((n-1)==0)
                   "no more"
               else
                   (n-1)) +
                   " bottles of beer on the wall.\n")
}

for(b <- (0 to 99).reverse)
    println(nBeers(b))
```

Answer (score 254, accepted):

```
scala> 10 to 1 by -1
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
```

Comment: @Felix: You're welcome. I should have also pointed out that there is also `until` that you can use in place of `to` to exclude the right-hand end-point from the range. The left-hand endpoint is always included.

Comment: I already knew about the until, the until is also a function on Integers, however, "by" must be a function on the range/iterator whatever is returned from the "to" and "until" functions. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Randall's answer is best, but I think `Range.inclusive(10, 1, -1)` deserves mention.

Answer (score 44):

The answer from @Randall is good as gold, but for sake of completion I wanted to add a couple of variations:

```
scala> for (i <- (1 to 10).reverse) {code} //Will count in reverse.

scala> for (i <- 10 to(1,-1)) {code} //Same as with "by", just uglier.
```

Comment: +1 for first one one, but second one is evil -- less readable than `by` and IMO shouldn't be used under any circumstances

Comment: Second one is evil but builds intuition on what's available

Comment: Thanks, `reverse` is nice for exclusive start and inclusive end e.g. `1 until x reverse` instead of `x - 1 to 1 by -1`.

Answer (score 16):

Scala provides many ways to work on downwards in loop.

1st Solution: with "to" and "by"

```
//It will print 10 to 0. Here by -1 means it will decremented by -1.     
for(i <- 10 to 0 by -1){
    println(i)
}
```

2nd Solution:  With "to" and "reverse"

```
for(i <- (0 to 10).reverse){
    println(i)
}
```

3rd Solution: with "to" only

```
//Here (0,-1) means the loop will execute till value 0 and decremented by -1.
for(i <- 10 to (0,-1)){
    println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Having programmed in Pascal, I find this definition nice to use:

```
implicit class RichInt(val value: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def downto (n: Int) = value to n by -1
  def downtil (n: Int) = value until n by -1
}
```

Used this way:

```
for (i <- 10 downto 0) println(i)
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I'm having trouble using this solution. Here is my stacktrace: `Error:(57, 17) value class may not be a member of another class
implicit class RichInt(val value: Int) extends AnyVal {
               ^`

Comment: As the error message (not a stack trace) suggests, you cannot define the value class inside of another class. Either define it outside of it, oike in an object, or remove the `extends AnyVal` part (which only serves to remove some overhead).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Range class:

```
val r1 = new Range(10, 0, -1)
for {
  i <- r1
} println(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use : 
`for (i <- 0 to 10 reverse) println(i)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i <- 10 to (0,-1))
```

The loop will execute till the value == 0, decremented each time by -1.