# How to iterate over range with negative step?

Tags: scala, loops, negative-number

Is there a way to do something like:

```
0 to -10 map { i=>
...
}
```

repl gives me:

```
scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Unit] = Vector()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decreasing for loop in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976955/decreasing-for-loop-in-scala)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
0 to (-10, -1)
```

or

```
0 to -10 by -1
```

Comment: +1, cool, I have no idea who answered first, would be nice if SO recorded seconds

Comment: This one wins by 1 second (hover the timeago text for the more detailed, less human-friendly date/time)

Comment: @Dylan nice tip, did not know that. That is tough though, Arjan is racking up the cred with an answer that, while more comprehensive, is generally the same as dbyrne's, with a difference of a single second!

Comment: well, I guess the nod goes here (sorry @dbyrne)

Comment: @virtualeyes [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13423180/timeline?asc=True) at your service ;-)

Answer (score 19):

Add the `by` clause:

```
0 to -10 by -1
res0: Range(0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10)
```